# How to move the popup window when the virtual kayboard is open in android?

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I have `EditText` and `Button` in popup-window.am show popup-window in bottom of the screen. When i try to enter details in `EditText`, the popup-window hide behind the soft-keyboard,not able to see the `EditText` and not able to solve the issue.Can any one know help me to solve this issue.

**popup-window code**

```
search_popup_inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
search_popup_view = search_popup_inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_popup, null, true);
search_popup = new PopupWindow(search_popup_view, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,true);

search = (EditText) search_popup_view.findViewById(R.id.search);
btn_search_enter = (Button) search_popup_view.findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
```

**After Button Click Show popup**

```
search_popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

        search_popup.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {

                    search_popup.dismiss();

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        //search_popup.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.line_lay), Gravity.TOP, locateView(view).left, locateView(view).bottom);
        search_popup.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.line_lay), Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, v.getHeight());
```

Comment: Change from popup window to DialogFragment you'll get the movement for free

Comment: @Blundell how can i show the dialog fragment in customized location.

Comment: You can't :-) hence comment & not answer

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

in the activity manifest file.